# reversing a number in C

Tags: c

Is this code right for reversing a number. Ignore the declaration of variables. Is there any other approach to do this?

```
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n-1];

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    t=a[i];
    while(t!=0)
    {
        last=t%10;
        printf("%d",last);
        t=t/10;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: well without knowing what the variables are we can not say that is correct.... Please contribute an [mcve]

Comment: What happened when you compiled and ran it ?

Comment: what do you want actually to reverse a number or array??

Comment: you definitly get out of bounds with `int a[n-1]`and`i<n` in the for loop

Comment: you will fail to reverse the number 0 using this code. but otherwise the logic for each element in the array seems correct

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev not if `t` is a non integer type. :)

Comment: @KamiKaze if t is non integer the code will not compile(unless you've overloaded the `%` operator)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev true.

Comment: "unless you've overloaded the % operator" - wishing you well in your endeavours in doing that in C.

Comment: Do all your test cases pass?  Is your test set complete?  If the answer to either question is "no", then it's not right.

Comment: P.S. It's totally wrong if any of the `scanf()` or `printf()` fails, since you never even look at the return values.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you mentioned having **undefined behavior** in 
`for(i=0;i<n;i++) { scanf("%d",&a[i]); }` as you are scanning `n` elements of array but you declared only `a[n-1]` i.e. one less. To overcome this declare `a[n]` and scan `n` elements.

Also here you are just reverse printing, `a[i]` doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be able to display your number in reverse, but there is easier ways to do so.

Declaring an array with a non-fixed size in the heap (`int a[n-1];`) is a functioning, albeit dirty, way of doing it. For this you rather use an allocation method as malloc.

Using scanf to simultaneously read on stdin and convert in integer is attractive but can only read on stdin. If you want to read on an other File Descriptor a combinaison of read and atoi is better.

Here's my way of doing it:

`int main()
{
    char buff[128];
    int tmp;
    int *t;

    if (read(0, buff, 127) <= 0)
        return (1);
    if ((tmp = atoi(buff)) < 1)
        return (1);
    if ((t = malloc(sizeof(int) * tmp)) == NULL)
        return (1);

    for (int i = 0; i < tmp; ++i) {
        if (read(0, buff, 127) <= 0)
            return (1);
        t[i] = atoi(buff);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tmp; ++i) {
        while (t > 0) {
            printf("%d", t % 10);
            t /= 10;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(t);
    return (0);
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your number to string, then use string reversing function on the string and after that convert the string back to number. Something along this lines:

```
int  v = 1234567890;
char cbuf[20];

 sprintf(cbuf,"%d",v);
 strrev(cbuf);
 sscanf(cbuf,"%d",&v);

printf("V = %d\n");
```

You can find strrev implementation somewhere on the web. Be aware that trailing zero will need special handling in this implementation, and that is not included in my code.